# Any scrolling plugin for jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to horizotally scroll my page when a peron clicks on some link. Is there any plugin available for jquery to do that? I saw localscroll scrollTo. None of them worked for me. I've been trying to get it work since 3 hours. I don't even get any error in firebug. Is there any better and advanced plugin to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a plugin for that. jQuery has [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop) and [`.scrollLeft()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft). You can use these two (as properties) in [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) as well. Combine them with [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset) and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to accomplish with this? If all you need is to scroll to a certain heading, paragraph or other HTML element, use an anchor:

```
<a href="#myanchor">Click here</a>

...

<a name="myanchor"><h3>My Family and Other Kinds of Animals</h3></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

"scrollTo" plugin did work for me. I used it two years ago to create a horizontally scrollable thumbnails gallery. Just take a look at the source code of www.bonadea.pl.